# Unable to access the Response of Http POST method; which I want to display the response in another components in a table using Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, http-post

i have designed two components: one is for file Upload and another for view the uploaded file status info in a table 
**I have successfully uploaded a file using HTTP POST method in one component and able to display the response received from my API in console.** 
but can not able to fetch the same response in the other component containing the structure of the table to displayed. currently getting **undefined** format for the data, i want to display in table.

the component.ts file containing the file upload function:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Component, OnInit, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
@Component({
  selector: 'app-analyzeiib',
  templateUrl: './analyzeiib.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./analyzeiib.component.sass']
})
export class AnalyzeiibComponent {
  title = 'fileUpload';
  selectedFile: File = null;
  public item:any;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private _router: Router) {}

  onFileChanged(event) {
    this.selectedFile = (event.target.files[0] as File);
  }

  onUpload(event: any) {
    const fd = new FormData();
    const f1 = this.selectedFile.name;
    console.log('the file is' + f1);
    console.log('the formdata is' + fd);
    if (!this.validateFile(f1)) {
        console.log('Selected file format is not supported');
        alert('Please select .msgflow or .subflow file');
        return false;
    }
    fd.append('file', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
    this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/exavaluconversion/webapi/fileUpload/single?actions=convert&username=oyishik@gmail.com', fd)
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        alert('Upload Successful');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
        this.item = res;
        console.log(this.item);
        JSON.stringify(this.item);


      if (event) {
            this._router.navigate(['/afterupload']);
         }
      });
  }
  validateFile(name: any) {
    const ext = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
    if (ext.toLowerCase() === 'msgflow' || ext.toLowerCase() === 'subflow') {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
  }

}
```

And the component.ts file generating the display of table:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { AnalyzeiibComponent } from '../analyzeiib/analyzeiib.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-afterupload',
  templateUrl: './afterupload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./afterupload.component.sass']
})
export class AfteruploadComponent implements OnInit{
  //url = `http://localhost:8080/exavaluconversion/webapi/myresource/filetable`;

  constructor(private http:HttpClient, private aniib:AnalyzeiibComponent){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(aniib.item));
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    return this.aniib.item;
    /*return this.http.get(this.url).toPromise().then(data => {console.log(data);
      for(let FileID in data)
        if(data.hasOwnProperty(FileID))
          this.items.push(data[FileID]);


      });*/

  }
}
```

I have tried the Routing navigation for component routing.
Is there any other way by which i can pass the `this.item` of 1st component to the 2nd component? i have tried many approaches explained in net, but to no avail. i am totally new to this Angular, can anyone suggest a possible approach?

[image: output response of 2nd component]

Comment: You should use @Output if parent child communication else use generic service to communication

Comment: @output in the file upload component?@pc_coder can you please tell me which procedure to be applied? i am completely new to this. thanks a lot for your comment